# Is there a way to force IE to render in IE8 standards OR HIGHER?

Tags: internet-explorer, standards

I know that to force IE to render in ie8, use:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

But is there a way to force IE to render **either ie8 OR ie9**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
... content="IE=8,9" />
```

Comment: a quick question: if i put "ie=8,9,edge" would this mean "try to render 8 first then 9 then the latest"? or will it just use edge and render using the latest version whichever it may be?

Comment: the docs state that IE will pick the HIGHESt supported rendering engine listed in the allowed UA.s. e.g IE10 would chose 9, since it supports that, but IE8 would only use 8, because it couldn't possibly understand 9.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

will render in the highest version available, without trying to emulate an earlier version, if that's what you meant.

Comment: i guess with this i might run into some problems where folks still use <ie8!? no?

Comment: @yaojiang: Well yes, but there's no `meta` tag to make IE7 behave like IE8.  :-)

Comment: im happy my company wont support <ie8 :)